# Error detection and correction with "feedback functionality" against several rules in data structures

Tags: algorithms

I have a complex data structure *DS* that needs to be checked for validity against several rules. If invalid, the *DS* has to be corrected. The correction with respect to one rule could result in an invalid state of *DS* again.

- There are *n* rules to check the data structure. If *DS* is valid for
  all rules, *DS* is valid. If *DS* is invalid with respect to at least
  1 rule, *DS* is invalid.
- For each rule, there is a correction algorithm that mutates *DS* in
  a way that it becomes valid with respect to the rule.
- But the correction of one rule could potentially invalidate *DS* with
  respect to another rule.

**Example**:

**Input**: DS (data structure), r1 (rule 1), r2 (rule 2)

**Function** *isValid(DS, r)* : Checks if DS is valid with respect to rule r1

**Function** *correct(DS, r)*: Mutates DS so that it is valid with respect to r

1. Let's assume that DS is not valid with respect to r1 but valid with respect to r2
2. Now we need to execute *correct(DS, r1)* to correct the DS.
3. It could now be that the correction of r1 has mutated DS in a way so that it is now invlaid with respect to r2. So we run a check: *isValid(DS, r2)*.
4. If the check yields false, we need to call *correct(DS, r2)*
5. This again could mutate DS in a way so that it is now again invalid with respect to r1 ...

So we need to check all rules and correct them as long as DS is invalid with respect to any rule. This could end in an endless loop, so I introduced a guard value. If DS cannot be corrected within for example 1000 iterations, DS is considered uncorrectable.

My current algorithm to cope with that is:

```
anyRuleViolated = true

WHILE anyRuleViolated AND ++iteration < guard:
    anyRuleViolated = false

    FOR EACH r in Rules:
        IF isValid(DS, r) == false:
            anyRuleViolated = true
            correct(DS, r)
```

Under search terms like "Error detection and correction" I only find correction mechanisms *without* that "feedback loop" (=correction of r1 can result in the violation of r2, ...). But I can't believe I'm the first person in the world running into that problem :)

These are my questions:

1. What do you think about the algorithm? Does it seem legit?
2. Do you know the category in which this problem lies? A search term or keyword I could use to search the web or publications for further insights into that problem?

Comment: The way I see it, when there are solutions, you want to minimize the number of correction. So I'd do a breadth-first search (by looking at structures as nodes, corrections as edges, and valid structures are target nodes). And cutting at a given depth seems like a good idea.

Comment: Can you edit the question to make it more focused?  "What do you think about...?" is too open-ended.  "Does it seem legit?" is too vague.  Can you identify what are the requirements or criteria by which the algorithm should be evaluated?  What would count as legit?  I wonder if it might help to tell us more about the nature of the rules.  That might make it easier to identify better approaches (if any exist).  You could look at abstract rewriting systems and the notion of confluence, though it might not help in your situation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluence_(abstract_rewriting).

Comment: I don't know the scope of Software Engineering.SE well enough to know if they will consider this a good fit there (given the above concerns about open-ended-ness).  If you think it's more appropriate there, you can delete the question here and re-ask it there (but don't have it open on two sites at once).  If you do that, I encourage you to edit the question to address/mention the feedback you've gotten so far.